# How to make a combobox.text change with a scroll on another comobox in "real time"?

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, combobox, selecteditem

I'm trying to make a combobox.text change in real time when I'm wheeling on another combobox.

Here is the code :

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBoxNomUnités.SelectionChangeCommitted
        Try
            ComboBox1.Text = GetStringFromQuery("SELECT qualité_unité FROM liste1 Where Nom_Unité = '" & ComboBox2.Text & "'")
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Problem is : Combobox2.text is always equal to the "previous" data, not the actual one corresponding to Combobox1.text.

[Example of the problem here](https://streamable.com/8zf5r6)
In this little mp4, you can see that the "Unit Quality" is always "late" vs the "Unit Names".

On another topic, a dev told me to use Combobox.selecteditem.tostring instead of Combobox.text but it's not working here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing occurs because you are using the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event. What you need is the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

In the first line, try replacing `Handles ComboBoxNomUnités.SelectionChangeCommitted` with `Handles ComboBoxNomUnités.SelectedIndexChanged` and give it a go.